# Problem with azure application settings variables

Tags: azure

I'm trying to set a new application setting for azure storage key, the problem is that the '==' at the end of the key is not been recognized, I try to generate a new key but it seems that very key ends in '=='

Comment: Where did you set the settings? In the portal or other tools?

Comment: What is the meaning of not recognized? Is it when you try to read the key in your application, those '==' are not coming?

Comment: Yes, @AnishK, that happens if I use the printenv command or if I print the environment variable form rails console

Comment: @Carlos, try to put your key in single quotes. I suspect this is the behavior of the linux env variable and not the azure or ruby on rails.

Comment: I did that @AnishK, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I test with portal and powershell, they all could work.

In the portal, go to your app service->Configuration->+New application setting and set your key there.

With powershell I use the below code to update it:

```
Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -AppSettings $hash
```

[image]

With these two ways, the key could be recognized, I check them in the kudu.

[image]

So if you are not using these way and you still fail to set it please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I'm using a Linux machine, with ruby on rails, when I execute the printenv  command for that specific key, the '==' characters are missing, and I can't connect to Azure blob storage

Comment: @Carlos Ernesto Medrano Guerrer, if you go to you app configuration and check the settings, is the variable with '=='?

Comment: Yes it is @George Chen

Comment: @Carlos Ernesto Medrano Guerrer, so you used which way to read app settings. Are you using `ENV['variable']`?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-ruby#access-environment-variables

Comment: @Carlos Ernesto Medrano Guerrer, could you use `ENV['variable']` to read settings?

Comment: @Carlos Ernesto Medrano Guerrer, any update now? If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: yes I am using the ENV['variable'], but still not showing the '==' at the end @George Chen